# 什么人 vs. 谁 usages？

Tags: grammar

I was watching a Chinese kid's movie about Chinese mythology to practice my Mandarin and learn about mythology when one of the characters said "什么人", which I interpreted to mean 谁. Is one more formal than the other? Do native speakers use them interchangeably or do they use one more than the other?

Comment: enter both into jukuu to get some idea

Comment: 什么人= what people/ who; 谁= who

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage may overlap, but they are often used in different situations to ask for different information.

誰 often asks identity, usually a name.  什麼人 often asks for status or role, 'what kind of a person' An example is this riddle: 什么人最笨？ 渔（愚）人.

It can also be used in the non-interrogative sense, as in 你是什麼人，便會吸引到什麼人. Whatever kind of person you are, that is the kind of person you will attract.  誰 would probably not be used in this type of sentence.

Comment: Another usage `什么人么（hyphen）！`  What a bad people !

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite fine but here they are

谁：

- Is more commonly used
- Is more polite

什么人：

- Used more in the olden days
- The person who says this may be a higher-class person or just arrogant
- Less polite
- In some cases is a question of one's status

Hope this helped.